# Open twitter/user/list intent in android application

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter

Who can help me to Intent twitter to open list section in tweeter app? 
This open intent window to choose how user want to open this link, but I want to open it in twitter app without chooser dialog.

```
try {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/user/lists/list")));
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/user/lists/list")));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an `Intent` from your app to another app(like twitter app), you can use

**Solution 1**

```
Intent i;
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
try {
i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("app package name");
if (i == null)
    throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(i);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

}
```

**Solution 2**

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");    
intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("app package name"));
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I know how to open twitter app, but i need automaticaly navigate to twitter.com/my_user/lists/my_list